# How to comunicate with hector_quadrotor UAV in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, uav, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have recently downloaded the hector_quadrotor stack and all works fine. I managed it to spawn my UAV in my simulation, but i don't know how to interact with it from my nodes out.... are there any topic's or so?? Or have you a link where this is described ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38372/how-to-comunicate-with-hector_quadrotor-uav-in-gazebo/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [wiki/hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins), the Gazebo plugin subscribes to [geomety_msgs/Twist](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) messages, so publishing these should allow you to control your UAV.

See the rest of that page for more info on the Gazebo plugins.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2